# Prev/Next Links With React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm building a simple CRUD application with React and React Router. As often, it includes a route that renders a list of items (`/items`) and another that renders the details of a single item (`/items/:id`).

I'd like this second component to include links to the previous and next items. But their IDs don't necessarily follow each other directly. So I cannot simply decrement/increment the ID of the current item to get that of the previous/next item (e.g.: if the ID of the current item is 3, that of the next one may be 5).

Do you have an idea of the most elegant way to handle this? Thank you for the help!

David

Comment: If you're saving the state of your application in a global store using something like Redux then you can find the next or previous item, assuming your array of objects' order is kept.

Comment: Where do your items come from? An API of some kind? If you control that API, you could add "next" and "prev" attributes to the data returned and use those to populate the href, similar to a HATEOAS model (https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS)